# How to configure webpacker gem to transpile stylus css?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, webpack-2, stylus, webpacker

Has anyone successfully configured [webpacker](https://github.com/rails/webpacker) to transpile [stylus css](http://stylus-lang.com/)? If so, would you be able to share your configuration or how you were able to transpile the stylus css?